# Editting HD Quicktime .mov files in Windows

Tags: windows, video-editing, quicktime, hdvideo

I recently purchased one of those new wave of point & shoot digicams (canon SD780) that shoot high definition 720p video.

Unfortunately it only writes to Quicktime files.

How can I go about editing these in Windows without spending any money?   I found a few MOV to AVI or WMV converters but am experiencing some quality degradation in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a [MOV plugin](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/Virtualdub) available for [**Virtualdub**](http://www.virtualdub.org/).

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) to convert videos from my Creative Vado HD to be Quicktime compatible.  It will work the other way as well.